# quartiles of box plot

Tags: statistics, quantile

I'm struggling with the meaning of quartiles , in this box plot how to compare these series like should I compare the upper $50$% of each series or the lower or  the $50$% between $1$st quartile and $3$rd quartile ?

**a:** $50$% of the values in series $A$ are greater than or equal to $50$% of the values in series $B$.

**b:** $75$% of the values in series $A$ are greater than or equal to $25$% of the values in series $B$.

**c:** $50$% of the values in series $B$ are less than or equal to $50$% of the values in series $A$.

**d:** $75$% of the values of series $A$ are less than or equal to $50$% of the values of series $B$
[image: a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine the statements in turn:

a: 50% of the values in series A are greater than or equal to 50% of the values in series B.

So look at the middle mark in Series A - the median - compare with the middle mark in Series B. It's False: 4 < 6.

b: 75% of the values in series A are greater than or equal to 25% of the values in series B.

Look at the Upper Quartile ($UQ_A$) for Series A, against the Lower Quartile ($LQ_B$) for Series B. Technically, it's true, as $6 \geq 4$, but as statement's go it is a weak one, as it would make more sense to compare $UQ_A$ with the median of Series B. I suggest you keep looking.

I will leave you to check c and d for yourself in the same way. One is True, the other False.